# Una función que busca una letra en un string arroja siempre 0

Tags: javascript, string, function

Estoy aprendiendo javascript a través del libro "Eloquent JavaScript, que, la verdad, está muy bien.
El caso es que he llegado a un ejercicio en el que hay que crear un función "contarFs" que calcule cuantas "f" hay en un string dado por el usuario. Mi código quedaría así:

```js
function contarFs(string, ch){
    let contador= 0;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < string.lenght; i++){
        if(string[i] == ch){
            contador += 1;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}


console.log(contarFs("ferryF", "f"));
```

He llegado al punto en que he visto el [resultado del ejercicio](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#3.3), he ajustado cosas y me da el mismo resultado. Sin embargo, cuando cojo el código del resultado, arroja el resultado esperable.

Llegados a este punto, no sé en qué me estoy equivocando o qué falta. Agradecería mucho una ayudita :C .

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico, la pregunta terminará cerrada por este motivo. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error tipográfico en el código que muestras.

La propiedad `string.lenght` realmente se escribe `string.length`.

Si corriges ese error tipográfico, el contador te da resultado = 1, ya que solo hay una letra `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error en el cálculo de la longitud de string, pones lenght y es length. Un despiste.